# No "Build Action" option in VS Express 2012 for Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2012

I've added an image file to my project which won't show up unless I set its 'Build Action' to 'Content' which can normally be done in the file properties window within Visual Studio. However, there is no such option for me. Anyone know what to do?

If it's of any relevance, I'm using a Phonegap template.

Thanks a lot